# Albedo and radiative forcing

Tags: atmospheric-science, climate-science

I'm a bit confused on the definitions of radiative forcing and albedo. Consider this textbook problem.

Suppose that the albedo of the earth increases by 0.01 in 265 years, ie $A(t) = 0.300+\frac{0.01}{265}t$ and suppose that solar radiation was constant at $E_s$ = 340 W/m$^2$ during this time.

Let $T_1$ be the change in atmospheric temperature of earth and $T_2$ the change in deep ocean temperature. We will use the following model

$$C_1 \frac{\partial T_1}{\partial t} = F - \frac{T_1}{\lambda} - \kappa(T_1-T_2) \\
C_2 \frac{\partial T_2}{\partial t} = \kappa(T_1-T_2).$$

where $F$ is the difference in radiative forcing relative to time 0 and $C_i$ is the heat capacity.

Sol'n: As I understand it, RF is defined as the difference between absorbed and reflected radiation. The albedo is defined as the fraction of sunlight *reflected*. So we would have

$$F(t) = (1-A(t))E_s-A(t)E_s-\Big((1-A(0))E_s-A(0)E_s\Big)
\\=2E_s(A(0)-A(t)) = -0.0256 \ [ W/m^2].$$

Would anyone mind telling me if I got the definitions right here?

Answer (score 1):

I think your definitions of albedo and radiative forcing are correct.  I think the result you have is wrong, as it needs to be a function of time, as albedo is time-dependent.

Comment: I think I forgot a $t$ in there yes